# Missing required positional argument (datetime)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new Flask and Postgres...

I am following this tutorial:
https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/

I have created a Entity like this:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Boolean, Date

from .entity import Entity, Base


class Strategy(Entity, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'strategies'

    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    startDate = Column(Date)
    endDate = Column(Date)
    allowTeamToVote = Column(Boolean)
    votingDeadline = Column(Date)
    isActive = Column(Boolean)

    def __init__(self, name, description, startDate, endDate, allowTeamToVote, votingDeadline, created_by):
        Entity.__init__(self, created_by)
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
        self.allowTeamToVote = allowTeamToVote
        self.votingDeadline = votingDeadline
        self.isActive = True

class StrategySchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Number()
    name = fields.Str()    
    description = fields.Str()
    startDate = fields.DateTime()
    endDate = fields.DateTime()
    allowTeamToVote = fields.Boolean()
    votingDeadline = fields.DateTime()
    isActive = fields.Boolean()
    created_at = fields.DateTime()
    updated_at = fields.DateTime()
    last_updated_by = fields.Str()
```

and a Post Method:

```
@app.route('/strategies', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def add_strategy():
    # mount Strategy object
    print(request.get_json())
    posted_strategy = StrategySchema(only=('name', 'description', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'allowTeamToVote', 'votingDeadline', 'isActive'))\
        .load(request.get_json())
print(posted_strategy.data)


    strategy = Strategy(**posted_strategy.data, created_by="HTTP post request")

    # persist Strategy
    session = Session()
    session.add(strategy)
    session.commit()

    # return created Strategy
    new_strategy = StrategySchema().dump(Strategy).data
    session.close()
    return jsonify(new_strategy), 201
```

What doesn't getting converted when .load(request.get_json()) method is called is all three datetime values.

I get the following error:

```
 __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'startDate', 'endDate', and 'votingDeadline'
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

1st print statement:

> {'objectives': [{'name': 'afasdfdsa'}], 'name': 'sdasdfdsaf',
>   'description': 'df
>   asfasdf', 'startDate': '05/31/2018', 'endDate': '05/31/2018',
>   'allowTeamToVote':
>   True, 'votingDeadline': '05/31/2018'}

2nd print statement:

> {'allowTeamToVote': True, 'name': 'asfdfsd', 'description':
>   'dsfasdfs'}

Full Exception:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2018 20:43:43] "OPTIONS /strategies HTTP/1.1" 200 - [2018-05-16 20:43:44,712] ERROR in app: Exception on /strategies
>   [POST] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1982, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py",
>   line 161, in wrapped_function
>       return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))   File
>   "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 33, in reraise
>       raise value   File "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\jason.virtualenvs\backend-foekiio5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1598, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "C:\projects\Python Projects\three-back\backend\src\auth.py", line
>   101, in decorated
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\projects\Python Projects\three-back\backend\src\main.py", line 41, in add_strategy
>       strategy = Strategy(**posted_strategy.data, created_by="HTTP post request") TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional
>   arguments: 'startDate', 'endDate', and 'votingDeadline'
>   127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2018 20:43:44] "POST /strategies HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: Can you add what the print statements are returning?

Comment: @AnilRedshift Add the print statement and full exception

Answer (score 0):

> What doesn't getting converted when .load(request.get_json()) method
>   is called is all three datetime values.

Your second `print` statement is outside of the function. So you are getting the wrong output.

> I get the following error:

You are passing a dict(key-value pairs) to the method but it is expecting positional arguments.

Change this line to this:

```
`strategy = Strategy(*posted_strategy.data.values(), created_by="HTTP post request")`
```

In all, something like this:

```
@app.route('/strategies', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def add_strategy():
    # mount Strategy object
    print(request.get_json())
    posted_strategy = StrategySchema(only=('name', 'description', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'allowTeamToVote', 'votingDeadline', 'isActive'))\
        .load(request.get_json())
    print(posted_strategy.data)


    strategy = Strategy(*posted_strategy.data.values(), created_by="HTTP post request")
```

Marshmallow has another way of achieving the same result, as noted in the [documentation here](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#deserializing-to-objects).

Comment: same result: `add_strategy
    strategy = Strategy(*posted_strategy.data.values(), created_by="HTTP post request")
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'endDate', 'allowTeamToVote', and 'votingDeadline'`

Comment: what does your second print statement now give you. Also try to print out `posted_strategy.data.values()`. It should return a list